# @Resource injection target is invalid. Only setter methods are allowed:

Tags: java, spring, jboss7.x, jboss5.x, ibatis

I have been trying to upgrade from JBOSS 5 to jboss 7 and I am getting the following exception.

```
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBAS011089: @Resource injection target is invalid.  Only setter methods are allowed: void com.myaccount.admin.manager.dao.ManagerDaoImpl.init(com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapClient)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor.processMethodResource(ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor.java:192)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor.deploy(ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor.java:153)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
```

Here is the code

```
  @Repository("managerDao")
  public class ManagerDaoImpl extends SqlMapClientDaoSupport implements ManagerDao {

  @Resource(name="sqlMapClient_ADMIN")
  public void init(SqlMapClient sqlMapClient) {
      setSqlMapClient(sqlMapClient);
   }

  ......
```

I googled but except the source code of the jboss jar I didn't find anything.

Comment: Just annotate the setter, like the exception says.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you'd look into `ResourceInjectionAnnotationParsingProcessor` `processMethodResource` source code you'd see:

```
if (!methodName.startsWith("set") || methodInfo.args().length != 1) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("@Resource injection target is invalid.  Only setter methods are allowed: " + methodInfo);
}
```

It checks if method name does not starts with `"set"` it throws an exception. So either rename your `init` method to start with `set` or just inject the field, annotate your `init` method with [@PostConstruct](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) annotation something like this:

```
  @Autowired
  private SqlMapClient sqlMapClient;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
      setSqlMapClient(sqlMapClient);
  }
```

Annotating the method with post construct may be better solution as maybe in future you'll need to add (or change) something more for initialization, so the only thing you'll need to do is to modify `init()` method.

Comment: Thanks , it solved the issue. I should have read that line before posting the question, I have changed the annotation to autowired